# Android Gradle support libraries must use same version

Tags: android, gradle

I already looked at every other questions and googled the impossible but I cannot find a way to use correct dependencies. Below there is my app Gradle build file:

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha01'
 }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
     jcenter()
     google()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
```

Comment: Well your build tool version and your appcompat version are different. Try compiling with same build tool version and appcompat library version.

Comment: I tryed but it says there is no 27.1.1 build tools

Comment: sorry, appcompat version should be less than or equal to the build tool version

Comment: try removing this line buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

Comment: Ok, i tried build tools 28.0.0. Still not working

Comment: Also tried to remove the lines as you said but still nothing

Comment: then your other implemented libraries are using an older version of app-compat or other support libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174083/discussion-between-mudit-sen-and-fumarja).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey just exclude the **appcompat** dependencies from the libraries which are using an older version of **appcompat** and support libraries. If you don't have these support libraries in your project then include them. In your question, `braintreepayments` is one of the libraries which using an older version of **card view** and **design** library. Try changing your gradle dependencies to

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation ('com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either downgrade appcompat library so its version be lowe then build tools version but still 27th, or upgrade build tools version up to appcompat. Check different compounds to find completely the same verstion

Answer (score 0):

Remove **buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"** from your gradle file.

Or you should check this-- **buildToolsVersion "27"**.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

The problem, as mudit_sen helped me find out, was the Braintree dependency:

> implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.0.0'

I removed that line as I don't need it and it was from a previous project and now everything is working as intended. Thank you very much.

### Update

For people that wants to use Braintree library the solution to me was to use

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
>
> implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'

with

> implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.4.0'